# Why is my compiler asking me to write an extension function for Map.forEach() here?

Tags: android, android-studio, foreach, compiler-errors, android-jetpack-compose

I started a simple Android app to play around with Compose UI and took a snippet of code from a [Google Developers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#sticky-headers) page on how to display lists with sticky headers.

I implemented the code and some of my other data model classes and everything worked fine. It complied and built, I saw my compose preview working as intended. Came back to my computer the next day, opened Android Studio, now I'm getting a compile-time error on my `grouped.forEach` statement inside the `PlantList` function. Android Studio recommends I create an extension function for Map<Char, List>.forEach() but I'm not sure why I'd have to do that.

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
(Char, List<Plant>) → Unit
Found:
(Char) → Unit
Expected 2 parameters of types Char, List<Plant>
Destructuring declaration initializer of type Char must have a 'component2()' function
```

The relevant code is below. The part that has me stumped is this was working on the same computer just the other day, and it still works on my other computer when I checkout the code over there. I don't think anything has changed about my development environment.

Layout.kt:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PlantsList(grouped: Map<Char, List<Plant>>) {
    Column {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text("My Plant List") },
        )
        LazyColumn {
            grouped.forEach { (initial, plantsForInitial) ->
                stickyHeader {
                    CharacterHeader(initial)
                }

                items(plantsForInitial) { plant ->
                    PlantListItem(plant)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PlantListItem(plant: Plant) {
    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Image(painter = painterResource(plant.image),
            contentDescription = "An image of you plant",
            modifier = Modifier.width(75.dp)
        )
        Column {
            Text(plant.name)
            Text("time to next water")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CharacterHeader(character: Char) {
    Column {
        Card(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp), elevation = 8.dp) {
            Text(character.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val orderedPlantList = returnTempPlantList().groupBy { it.name[0] }
        setContent {
            PlantReminderTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    PlantsList(orderedPlantList)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    val orderedPlantList = returnTempPlantList().groupBy { it.name[0] }
    PlantReminderTheme {
        PlantsList(orderedPlantList)
    }
}
```

Plant.kt:

```
data class Plant(
    var id: Int,
    var name: String,
    var image: Int
)
```

data class PlantList(var plants: List)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the parenthesis from the lambda

Comment: Ok, thanks. However now I'm getting an error in the `items` function. It doesn't like the `plantsForInitial` item I'm passing in. It expect an `int` but I'm passing in a `List<Plant>`. Shouldn't it know to expect the list because `grouped` is a map of `Char` and `List<Plant>`?

Comment: Oh that's just because by default it may be thinking that you are passing the size of the list. Just use named args — ```items(items = plantsForInitial)```